# The Best Way of Trimming Spaces in a String

Tags: java, regex, trim

How do I trim spaces inside leaving only one space taking consideration of performance?

> ```
> Input:
>      AA     BB
> Output:
> AA BB
>
> Input:
> A      A
> Output:
> A A
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
System.out.println("     AA     BB".replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim());
```

Output:

```
AA BB
```

Note: Unlike some of the other solutions here, this also replaces a single tab with a single space. If you don't have any tabs you can use " {2,}" instead which will be even faster:

```
System.out.println("     AA     BB".replaceAll(" {2,}", " ").trim());
```

Answer (score 7):

Replace two or more spaces `"\\s{2,}"` by a single space `" "` and do a `trim()` afterwards to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces as you showed in the 1st example.

```
output = input.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " " ).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

`"Hello a a g g a   gag gs    gs@".replaceAll( "[ ]+{2}", " ") ).trim();`

Answer (score 0):

There are correct answers here, e.g.:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " " ).trim();
```

But I think it's also important to choose the correct question. Instead of asking about trimming a `String` using regular expressions, why not just ask about trimming the `String`, and allow people answering to show you the best strategy?

There may well be better ways to collapse spaces than to use a regular expression. There are certainly *other* ways.

Comment: The question has been edited. Now could you please show me a better way? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that there was an indisputably better way. If I knew one I would certainly have told you without insisting the question be changed first. I just wanted to point out that it was possible that you were limiting responses based on an assumption of the correct strategy. I would say that unless you have very strong performance reasons to want to experiment with alternatives, the regex route is probably what I would do.